# Objective C - Format integer with chars in the middle

Tags: objective-c, string, formatting

How do I convert, for example, the number 123 as: "00\00\00\12\3" ?
Can stringwithformat do that?

Comment: Why is it written that way in the first place? Can you give a few more examples -- is there always the same pattern of slashes? Is it always slashes? More details would help this question be useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the earlier answers to this harder to read, so here's a simpler version than others suggested:

```
NSString *stringByAddingSlashesToNumber(int num) {
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%09i", num];

    // we start at index 2 to skip the first pair, and increment by 3
    // because we need to skip the two digits and the added backslash
    for (NSUInteger idx = 2; idx < str.length; idx += 3) {
        [str insertString:@"\\" atIndex:idx];
    }

    return [str copy];
}
```

Hopefully the logic is a bit easier to follow, and does what you expect.